# Listen to virtual keyboard presses without edit text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-virtual-keyboard

Is there a way to get key events when forcing keyboard this way in Fragment onCreateView method:

```
    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Also would need the keyboard to be in numeric mode.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen keyboard presses if you override onKeyDown method in your activity

```
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            ...
            return true;
            ...
        default:
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to show soft keyboard even if you dont have any edit text to focus on,

**first-**

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInputFromWindow(viewToAnchorTo.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

**Second-**

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```